# Which will be the phonegap version if i build from phonegap cloud service?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Iam working on  a phonegap application, i have below tag in each of my pages;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"> </script>
```

and i made build using phonegap cloud service (https://build.phonegap.com/apps),
i want to know  which phonegap version build i'll get from **phonegap cloud service**, since i have not mentioned the phonegap version in tag (as shown above)? I have already made build using this service but **did'nt find anyway to understand the version from build**. Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the version via config.xml. see [Docs > PhoneGap Version](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)

Currently, PhoneGap/Cordova 2.9.0 is the latest supported version.
Sample:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
```

from the docs:

> If you do not *set phonegap-version*, your app will be set to the current default version.

Currently, 2.9.0 is the default version.

from the docs:

> currently supported versions are 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.5.0, 2.7.0, and 2.9.0 (default).

If you want to check the version with JavaScript, use

```
device.cordova
```

Comment: I know how to set the phonegap version. But,  where they have mentioned<<"not setting phonegap-version results in the most recent version">>?

Comment: I rechecked the docs and edited my answer. Not setting the version will use the default version. The latest is the current default.

Comment: but my device tells  2.3.0. is default.

Comment: Upload again to the build service with your own config.xml to force a new version.